# proof with multiplicative inverses mod n

Tags: proof-writing, inverse

I am trying to write a proof for-

show that if [b] and [c] are both multiplicative inverses of [a] in Zn, then b congruent c (mod n)

I don't know a lot about multiplicative inverse proofs and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you search the site you'll find more than one solution demonstrating that multiplicative inverses are unique. Even if they aren't exactly your situation, they will point out to you exactly why this is so (sometimes in a more general context.)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is commutative and associative.
$$[b] = [b][1] = [b]([c][a]) = [c]([b][a]) = [c][1] = [c]$$